# what is this で in front of はなした doing?

Tags: grammar

In my textbook, there are instructions for a composition. 
These instructions are the following:
こんど、国際交流協会で座談会があります。テーマは「文化や習慣の違い」です。
下のことについて、みんなで座談会の観衆尾をしましょう。

Then, a list of further specifying instructions follows, specifying various topics to talk about. One of them is the following:

で話したことをまとめてメールで送りましょう
It is this で at the very beginning which I have never seen so far ^^ Mostly because I've never seen particles taking the lead position in a sentence xD
Here's my attempt at translation. 
=> "Please send the talked about things all in one piece with E-mail."

EDIT: Since some asked for more context, I uploaded a scan of the full exercise.
https://www.docdroid.net/hBn7YgR/1.pdf
Its number 5,  チャレンジしましょう.

Comment: Typo? 観衆尾をしましょう→観衆をしましょう。

Comment: 文脈の引用の仕方に問題あり。最低でも、その「で」で始まる文の直前の部分も書き写してくれないとね。これじゃや回答する人も自信を持って回答できないでしょう。

Comment: -1 This is rediculous.  It so clearly says 「1）で話したこと」 and not 「で話したこと」.

Comment: @l'électeur:  r*i*diculous.  #ftfy

Comment: `みんなで座談会の観衆尾をしましょう` ←問題集には「みんなで座談会の**練習**をしましょう」って書いてあるやん～もおおお～～

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Now that you posted the link to the PDF, it's obvious that 友達や先生に１）で話したことをまとめてメールで送りましょう means "Let's send emails to your friends and teacher about what you discussed in #1". The で is marking section #1 as where the discussion took place.

Comment: This is definitely right; the typography is confusing.

Answer (score 0):

Building on l'electeur's comment, it is likely just で which precludes a sentence that supposedly builds on the previous statement.

> 先生はもう帰りました。で、どうしましょうか？ Professor already left. So, what should we do?

In your case, the instruction just tells you that after observing the roundtable discussion you should all gather and summarize your thoughts and email them.